# React show toggle showing all children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using react.js and im trying to have a `<ul>` with each `<li>` having a child `<ul>`. When an icon in the `<li>` is clicked Im trying to show its child `<ul>`. The current way I have it its showing ALL the `<li>`'s children instead of just its own corresponding child.

```
    const FooterMenu = (props) => {

    const { menuName } = props;
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState([]);
    const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (menuName) {
            axios.get(``)
                .then(response => {
                   setMenu(response.data);
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log('[Page] error', error); //TO-DO: remove before prod deployment
                    //TO-DO: add redirect to error page
                })
        }
        
    }, [menuName]);

    return (
        <ul>
            { menu.map(row => {
                return (
                    <li className="footer-menu-icon footer-menu-item">
                        <i className={`fas showSubLinks ${row.SubMenus.length >= 1 ? (showDetails ? 'fa-minus' : 'fa-plus') : 'fa-angle-right'}`} onClick={() => setShowDetails(() => !showDetails)}></i>
                        <a href={row.MenuLink} target={row.LinkTarget ? row.LinkTarget : '_self'}>{row.MenuText}</a>
                        {row.SubMenus.length >= 1 && showDetails  ? (
                            <ul className="subMenu-items">
                                {
                                    row.SubMenus.map(row => {
                                        return (
                                            <li>
                                                <a href={row.MenuLink} target={(row.LinkTarget) ? row.LinkTarget : '_self'}>{row.MenuText}</a>
                                            </li>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </ul>
                        ) : (
                            <></>
                        )}
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    );
};

export default FooterMenu;
```

I know the `showDetails` is to blame but cant seem to wrap my head around how to do this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the the showDetails in the menu array itself as a property like below, when the menu is loaded it will have the default value which is false and after that the buttons would toggle it to true and false

```
const Menu = () => {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState([
    {
      MenuText: "Submenu",
      SubMenus: [
        {
          MenuLink: "#",
          MenuText: "Submenu"
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      MenuText: "Submenu1",
      SubMenus: [
        {
          MenuLink: "#",
          MenuText: "Submenu"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <ul>
      {menu.map((row, i) => {
        return (
          <li className="footer-menu-icon footer-menu-item">
            <i
              className={`fas showSubLinks ${
                row.SubMenus.length >= 1
                  ? row.showDetails
                    ? "fa-minus"
                    : "fa-plus"
                  : "fa-angle-right"
              }`}
              onClick={() => {
                const updatedMenu = [...menu];
                updatedMenu[i].showDetails = !updatedMenu[i].showDetails;
                setMenu(updatedMenu);
              }}
            ></i>
            <a
              href={row.MenuLink}
              target={row.LinkTarget ? row.LinkTarget : "_self"}
            >
              {row.MenuText}
            </a>
            {row.SubMenus.length >= 1 && row.showDetails ? (
              <ul className="subMenu-items">
                {row.SubMenus.map((row) => {
                  return (
                    <li>
                      <a
                        href={row.MenuLink}
                        target={row.LinkTarget ? row.LinkTarget : "_self"}
                      >
                        {row.MenuText}
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            ) : (
              <></>
            )}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just separate submenu to another component with own  showDetails state.

```
{row.SubMenus.length >= 1 &&  (
   <ul className="subMenu-items">
     {
      row.SubMenus.map(row => <SubMenuComponent />)
     }
   </ul>
)}
```